# Слежение за изменениями DOM в iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, события

Родительская страница и iframe лежат на одном домене. Каким образом можно установить в documentElement iframe MutationObserver?

Вот так не работает:

```
var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver
(
    function observe(mutations)
    {
        mutations.map(function(mutation){console.log(mutation.addedNodes);});
    }
); 
observer.observe(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentDocument.documentElement, {attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true});
```

Comment: Попробуйте слушать события в самом iframe, а родителю передавать событие при помощи [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: vihtor, по определённым причинам я не могу изменять iframe (домен не мой, я пишу расширение).

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, нельзя просто так взять и добавить событие (а MutationObserver является таковым) в непрогруженный document.
Вот это будет работать:

```
var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver
(
    function observe(mutations)
    {
        mutations.map(function(mutation){console.log(mutation.addedNodes);});
    }
); 
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].onload = function()
{
    observer.observe(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentDocument.documentElement, {attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true});
};
```